# Orthonormalize subsets in a sequence of subsets of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a infinite dimensional, separable hilbert space over the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in H$ be a sequence of subsets of $H$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:$

$A_n$ is linearly independent, infinite, countable.

Let $A= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $A$ is linearly independent.

Is it possibile orthonormalize $A_n$ getting $B_n$ such that $B= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ is orthonormal?

Thanks

Comment: Which relation between $A_n$ and $B_n$ do you want to have? Should they span the same space?

Comment: @gerw $B_n$ is the orthonormalization of $A_n$ or $span(A)=span(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with the requirement of the comment, this cannot be achieved. Consider, e.g.,
$$A_1 = \{(1,0)\}, A_2 = \{(1,1)\}$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $A$ is linear independent
and by $span(A_n) = span(B_n)$, you can only scale the vectors in $A_1$ and $A_2$. Thus, they will never become orthogonal.

Comment: thanks for this counterexamples